# Angle between two lines beginning at one side of the line

Tags: math, geometry, line, pseudocode, angle

I have two lines specified by two points with x and y coordinate each. The first point (where the lines begin) *is equal* meaning that I have 3 points A, B and C where one line is from A to B and the other one from A to C. I would then want to calculate the angle between the two lines **starting at the right side of the first line**. The result needn't be accurate I actually only need to know if this angle is *greater* or *less* than 180° (π rad). Thanks for any help - you needn't write any code, pseudocode and/or explanation would be great.

Comment: cosine rule. a^2 = b^2 + c^2 – 2bc cos(theta). I'm sure there are better ideas though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define some notation:

```
A := (a1, a1).
B := (b1, b2).
C := (c1, c2).
```

Then the determinant D of the matrix

```
1 a1 a2
1 b1 b2
1 c1 c2
```

determines whether `C` lies left or right of the directed line `AB` [cf. Computational Geometry - Berg, van Kreveld, Overmars, Schwarzkopf - Chapter 1, Exercise 1.4 a)]

Now, you can subtract row 1 from rows 2 and 3:

```
1 a1     a2
0 b1-a1 b2-a2
0 c1-a1 c2-a2
```

and calculate `D` from the first column to get:

```
(b1-a1)*(c2-a2) > (c1-a1)*(b2-a2)
```

as the condition representing whether `C`lies on the left of `AC` or not. Of course, lying on the right (resp. left) means that the angle is < 180 (resp. > 180)

**Example**

```
A = (0, 0)
B = (0, 1)
C = (1, 0)
```

Then `AB` is the vertical segment (y axis) and `C` is clearly on its right side. The condition

```
(b1-a1)*(c2-a2) > (c1-a1)*(b2-a2)           ineq(1)
```

becomes:

```
0 > 1
```

which is `false`, meaning that `C` is not on the left of `AB` (as expected)

**Visualization**

To visualize the condition we can translate the three points `A`, `B` and `C` until `A` becomes `(0,0)`. This is an innocuous transformation because the condition in ineq(1) subtracts `a1` and `a2` from the coordinates of `B` and `C`. With this translation ineq(1) becomes:

```
b1*c2 > c1*b2                              ineq(2)
```

Now, lets visualize the three points (ignore for now the brown lines relative to `C' = (c'1, c'2)`):

[image]

The product `b1*c2` is the area of the RED rectangle. The product `c1*b2` is the area of the GREEN rectangle. The picture shows that RED < GREEN meaning that `C` is on the right.

Now, mentally move `C` around, say to `C'` and visualize the new RED and GREEN rectangles. The inequality remains valid as long as `C` is on the right.

Not convinced yet? Well, write a program that dynamically reproduces this picture while you change the position of `C` and voila! (Or study some more Mathematics and solve the book's exercise ;)

**Note:** Be aware that these rectangles have a sign. In the picture they both have a positive area, however, in general, the products `b1*c2` and `b2*c1` will have a sign.

Comment: @OliverBorchert I've added a picture that will help you visualize what's going on.

Comment: _great_ explanation! Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [vector product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) . If you calculate the 3D vectors for the line segments AB and AC, they will both have zero z components.

Because the vectors AB and AC lie in the xy plane, the only possible non-zero component of their vector product is the z component - so this is the only component you need to calculate.

The **sign** of this z component will tell you whether the angle is greater than or less than 180 degrees depending on your orientation.